# Apache Signed certificate by know authority and client certificate self-signed

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

I've been investigating about this and it work with the apache SSL option

```
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
```

I have the following virtualhost configuration.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    SSLCertificateFile /root/test-https-certificate/test.company.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/test-https-certificate/research.company.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /root/test-https-certificate/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
    SSLCARevocationPath /root/ssl-authentication/crl
    SSLCARevocationFile /root/ssl-authentication/crl/crl.pem
    SSLCADNRequestFile /root/ssl-authentication/client-cert-issuing-ca.crt
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpsdocs/topsecret>
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpsdocs/topsecret
    ServerName test.company.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem now is that everyone having certificate or not can access to my restricted folder, reading documentation about the mod_ssl of apache I've found the option **SSLRequire** but how can I implement it, when I use it in my  tag it redirects me to the default **DocumentRoot** of apache.

And other doubt.. in a security point of view what I'm doing is correct? Having self-signed certificate for clients and one signed by an official entity for the server?

Comment: If you're not doing any validation on the client certificates, why use them at all?

Comment: I wan't to validate the user and the company of the certificate in order to allow the access to the resource. this is correct?